# Loops in R and Alternatives

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a matrix (1051*1051) that has 0zeros along its diagonal and values greater than 0zero everywhere else.  The goal is to conditionally reassign some values in the matrix.  For example, the criteria I would like to implement is this:  If any element is greater than, say, 400, then that row/column element will be assigned a 0zero value.

This is how my code is setup as of now:

```
dl <- 400       # condition

for( i in 1:dim(DIST)[1] ) {
    for( j in 1:dim(DIST)[1] ) {
        if( DIST[i,j] > dl ) {
             DIS[i,j] <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

DIST is the original matrix (1051*1051).

DIS is the copy of DIST and to be edited.

My question:
Is there any other way to do this?  A faster way?

I have read that loops in R should be avoided.  If anyone has a more efficient way please share.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the entire row and column setting to 0 for elements that are greater than the condition? Several of us are confused?

Comment: Just the element in DIS[i,j]==0 iff DIS[i,j]>dl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [] assignment:

```
DIST[DIST>400] <- 0
```

See `?'['` for how this works.  The key is that `DIST>400` produces a logical vector of length `length(DIST)` (the number of elements in DIST), consisting of TRUE if the element is >400 and FALSE otherwise.  That vector is then used to subset the matrix, and only the selected elements get assigned to.

Comment: You nailed the question.  This was what I was looking for.  Sorry about the confusion on row/column.  I do not want the entire row/column to 0zero.  Just the element that violates the condition.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
DIS[DIST > d1] <- 0
```

Full example:

```
n <- 10
d1 <- 400
DIST <- matrix(as.integer(runif(n^2)*1e4), n, n)
DIS <- DIST
DIS[DIST > d1] <- 0
```

Comment: there you go... I'm wondering: should I delete my answer as it is the same but you were faster or is that bad habits?

Comment: Cloning the vector to DIS before comparison and assignment is unnecessary and computationally (memory and speed) inefficient.  The assignment happens after the logical comparison, so `DIST[DIST>400] <- 0` works fine.

Comment: @cbeleites: Given that your answer is a two-liner and exactly reproduces djhurio's more detailed example, I'd go ahead and delete it.  I gave you a +1 so you can get a Disciplined badge for deleting ;-).

Comment: gsk, I understood the question so that a copy should be done [deleting: :-) turns out I can only vote that my answer should be deleted. ]

Comment: @cbeleites: Good point about the question asking for it.  He also asked for faster though, so I went with modification.  But it does explain why DIS showed up in both your answers. :-)

Comment: DIST is the original/Master matrix that once it is populated I don't want to mess with it (I plan to create some matrices that are bigger than 1051*1051 so I just want to create it once and not touch it).  DIS is the copy of DIST... and DIS is what I want to manipulate.  Since DIST==DIS, DIS[DIS > dl] <- 0 works just fine.  I can't believe how fast this operation is !

Comment: @wisfool: Use the vector, Luke!  It's impressively fast ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of doing this treating the matrix as a vector and using the `row()` and `col()` functions to return the relevant rows and columns of the entries that are greater than a condition.

First, create some dummy data:

```
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(runif(25), ncol = 5)
diag(m) <- 0
```

Next we use `row()` and `col()` to return a matrix with the row or col index for each entry in the matrix.

```
mr <- row(m)
mc <- col(m)
```

`mr` looks like this, for example:

```
> mr
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4
[5,]    5    5    5    5    5
```

Now we set out condition value, and select those cells of `m` that exceed the condition:

```
cond <- 0.95
want <- which(m > cond)
```

Having these cells that exceed the condition, we extract the unique row and column indexes for these cells

```
rwant <- unique(mr[want])
cwant <- unique(mc[want])
```

these are the rows and columns you want setting to 0.

Here we do this setting to zero, first copying `m` in `m2` for comparison:

```
m2 <- m
m2[rwant, ] <- 0
m2[, cwant] <- 0
```

Here are the two matrices:

```
> m
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.89838968 0.2059746 0.4976992 0.9347052
[2,] 0.3721239 0.00000000 0.1765568 0.7176185 0.2121425
[3,] 0.5728534 0.66079779 0.0000000 0.9919061 0.6516738
[4,] 0.9082078 0.62911404 0.3841037 0.0000000 0.1255551
[5,] 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414 0.7774452 0.0000000
> m2
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3] [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.89838968 0.2059746    0 0.9347052
[2,] 0.3721239 0.00000000 0.1765568    0 0.2121425
[3,] 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000    0 0.0000000
[4,] 0.9082078 0.62911404 0.3841037    0 0.1255551
[5,] 0.2016819 0.06178627 0.7698414    0 0.0000000
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood what row/column element meant. I thought you meant the entire row or column should be set to zero.

Comment: I just deleted my post because he did ask for entire row/column set to zero and I'd mis-read.  Temporary undeleted while waiting for his answer as to what he really wanted.

Comment: That's what I understood as well (entire column to be set to 0).

Comment: I think this is the source of the confusion: "... then that row/column element will be assigned a 0zero value."  What I meant by "row/column element" was if DIS[i,j] violates the condition, than DIS[i,j] <- 0, for any i,j within dim(DIS)

Comment: @Gavin Simpson I appreciate your answer.  I learned new ways to manipulate in R with row(), which(), unique().  I still consider myself a 'newbie' so these tools help a lot.